# Using Java/Webdriver I want to select the second element with the same name

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following piece of java for clicking an icon.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='icon']")).click();
```

I cannot select a unique ID, as they change everytime I login. There are three classNames with  'icon' as the className on the page, and I want webdriver/java/selenium to click the second one.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[class='icon']")).get(1).click();
```

Or this, if it makes it easier for you to understand:

```
List<WebElement> icons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[class='icon']"));
WebElement icon = icons.get(1);
icon.click();
```

If you have 3 such elements, then you can call `icons.get` with 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: That did it! Get(1) basically means, skip 1. So if I would use get(2), he would skip 1 and 2, and click on the 3rd icon with the same classname, right? Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Added an extended description (see updated answer). It is essentially the same, but in general, method `findElements` returns a `List` object. In order to get an element from that object, you can use `get` (as for any other `List` object, regardless of Selenium)... you're welcome!